# REGKEY doesn't work if set by InnoSetup

Tags: windows, registry, windows-8.1, inno-setup

I use InnoSetup (v5.5.9) to create an Installer for my application. In the inno-installer-script, I use the following statement to make the application start with admin-privileges:

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers; \
ValueType: string; ValueName: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; ValueData: "RUNASADMIN"; \
Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist uninsdeletekey; MinVersion: 6.2;
```

This works on all our test machines from Win7 up to Win10 (all x64). But there are some machines running Win8.1 (also x64), where it the application seems to ignore this key.

I could track down the error to the following:

When right-clicking on the application.exe and checking the "run as admin" flag under compatibility, it sets the above mentioned key in the registry and additionally the same key under `HKEY_USERS`, which is where it actually reads the key from. When setting the key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` manually or using InnoSetup it is not taken to `HKEY_USERS`.

Has anyone an idea why that is?

Thanks!

Comment: This just cannot work on any 64-bit system. You must have you test environment messed up. You have to use `HKLM64`. See [Set “RUNASADMIN” application compatibility flag in Inno Setup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39498971/850848).

Comment: Huh! It's actually a 32bit application, which is installed on a x64 system - but you know what: that fixed it anyway! Thank you very much!

How did that ever work for our old installations... ???