# Why is it not recommended to use HKCR registry root key in Inno Setup?

Tags: registry, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have to write a value to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key. In order to do that I would write:

```pascal
RegWriteStringValue(HKCR, '<Root>', '<SubKey>', '<Value>');
```

But when I looked in the documentation I saw this:

> Using HKCR is not recommended, use HKA with the Subkey parameter set to "Software\Classes" instead.

I'd like to know what's the difference between the two?

Also, I've noticed that in the examples in the documentation they use `HKEY_AUTO` instead of `HKA`. Are those the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably based on Microsoft recommendations for avoiding use of [`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key):

> It is primarily intended for compatibility with the registry in 16-bit Windows.

> To change the settings for the interactive user, store the changes under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes** rather than **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**.

> To change the default settings, store the changes under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes**

> Processes running in a security context other than that of the interactive user should not use the **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** key with the registry functions.

Comment: Are those `HKA` and `HKEY_AUTO` the same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.